# How to stop animation block from making uibutton background image flicker

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have two buttons in a view controller that I animate up and then back to their original positions when pressed. 50% of the time there is a discernible gap that appears between the top of the button and it's background image. I think it has to do with using spring/damping but I don't want to not use that. I tried rounding to the nearest whole CGFloat both the button frame and destination coordinates, no luck. Is there a work around to this?

```
    let profileMainScreenButtonAnimateToY = -ceil((profileMainButton.frame.origin.y - 45.0))
    let profileStandingsButtonAnimateToY = -ceil((profileStandingsButton.frame.origin.y - 45.0))

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0.8, options: [.CurveEaseInOut], animations: { () -> Void in

        self.profileMainButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, profileMainScreenButtonAnimateToY)
        self.profileStandingsButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, profileStandingsButtonAnimateToY)

        }) { (Bool) -> Void in


    }
```

[image: That little yellow line at the top]

It's difficult to see in the image but there is a yellow horizontal line at the top of the image.

Comment: Try using `profileMainButton.bounds.origin.y` instead of `profileMainButton.frame.origin.y`

Comment: Nope, no dice. Tried tightening up the image scaling as well with contentAlignmentVertical/Horizontal, no on that too.